# How do I use $map in a MongoDB $projection

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a database with documents like this:

```
{
   _id: 123, 
   metrics: [{ 
               _id: ObjectID(…), 
               name: 'foo',
               steps: [1, 2, 3, …], 
               values: [10, 12, 13, …]
              },
              { 
               _id: ObjectID(…), 
               name: 'bar',
               steps: [1, 2, 3, …], 
               values: [1.2, 1.2, 1.3, …]
              },
             ]
}
```

Now my objective is to retrieve all documents, but `$map` all array entries to their `name` attribute, discarding the other fields. I thought I could do it like this:

```
pipeline = [{'$project': {'metrics': {'$map': {'input': '$metrics', 'in': '$this.name'}]
results = client.db.runs.aggregate(pipeline)
```

But the result has just `None` values for each array entry (`{'metrics': [None, None, None, …]}`), as if the requested field `name` did not exist. But it does. I've also tried with the id field, to no avail. I can see in inspecting the data that the fields are there. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) you can use `as` to define temporary variable which will represent single document from your `metrics` and then reference that variable in `in` part.

```
db.col.aggregate([{'$project': {'metrics': {'$map': {'input': '$metrics', as: 'metric', 'in': '$$metric.name' } } } }])
```

or you can directly refer to a temporary variable `this`

```
db.col.aggregate([{'$project': {'metrics': {'$map': {'input': '$metrics', 'in': '$$this.name' } } } }])
```

The thing is that every time you use single dollar sign, you refer to a field that's defined in the document that's being processed in current pipeline stage. Additionally you can use double dollar sign to refer to some variables that can be defined by operators like `$map`, `$filter` and so on.

You can try your initial code for following document:

```
{
    _id: 123, 
    this: { name: "x" },
    metrics: [{ }, { } ]
}
```

and you will get an array with two `x` values as there are two metrics but every iteration refers to the same `this.x` value:

```
{ "_id" : 123, "metrics" : [ "x", "x" ] }
```

Comment: I know, but it says in the documentation: _as - Optional. A name for the variable that represents each individual element of the input array. If no name is specified, the variable name defaults to `this`._ Specifying a name also doesn't change the result.

Comment: Update: The double `$$` seemed the problem. Not sure when to use it. I tried it before unsuccessfully, but now it works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Could you elaborate on the use of the double dollar sign or link the relevant documentation? Then I could accept this answer.

Comment: @oarfish sure, modified my answer